# resize-temp-buffer doesn't work in my code when 2 windows are diplayed into the frame

Tags: message

I'm searching for a way to display messages while replacements are proposed to the users of a script.

I tried to write a macro but I'm in trouble with this code:

```el
(defmacro with-user-explanation (MESSAGE &rest body)
  "DOCSTRING."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(let* ((temp-buffer-resize-mode temp-buffer-resize-mode)
      (frame-config (current-frame-configuration))
      (fit-frame-to-buffer t))
     
     (temp-buffer-resize-mode 1)
     (resize-temp-buffer-window)
        (unwind-protect
       (progn
         (with-output-to-temp-buffer "REPLACEMENT INFO"
           (princ ,MESSAGE))

         ,@body)
     ;; *CLEANUP*
      (progn
        (kill-buffer "REPLACEMENT INFO")
        (set-frame-configuration frame-config)))))

(defun my-ue-test () 
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((a (point-min-marker))
       (z (point-max-marker)))
      (with-user-explanation
      "This message provide info about this specific string replacement in the document."
    (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil a z)))))
```

I have 2 issues:

1. When I run the function with 2 windows opened:
   [image] the temp buffer is not resized:
   [image] I need it to be resized: [image] It is correctly resize when I run the function with only one window diplayed.
2. At the function exit, the layout (the color) of the pointer has changed (from white to gray). **I moved this issue here: [Cursor's color differs from what specified in the frame parameters](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63252/15606)**

**Edit.** Maybe using a temp-buffer to display MESSAGE is not a good idea. Everything is messed up, also with the Arch Stanton's solution, if I use e.g. `occur`:

```el
(defun my-ue-test ()
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((a (point-min-marker))
           (z (point-max-marker)))
      (with-user-explanation
          "This message provide info about this specific string replacement in the document."

        (occur "foo")
        (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil a z)))))
```

[image]

**EDIT 2.** This last issue is solved with `set-window-dedicated-p`:

```el
(defmacro with-user-explanation (MESSAGE &rest body)
  "DOCSTRING."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(let* ((temp-buffer-resize-mode temp-buffer-resize-mode)
          (frame-config (current-frame-configuration))
          (fit-frame-to-buffer t)
    
          (temp-buffer-show-function
           (lambda (bufname)
             (display-buffer bufname '(display-buffer-at-bottom)))))

     (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (with-output-to-temp-buffer "REPLACEMENT INFO"
             (princ ,MESSAGE))
       (fit-window-to-buffer (get-buffer-window "REPLACEMENT INFO"))
       (set-window-dedicated-p (get-buffer-window "REPLACEMENT INFO") t)
           ,@body)
       ;; *CLEANUP*

       (progn
         (kill-buffer "REPLACEMENT INFO")
         (set-frame-configuration frame-config)))))
```

Comment: You can show a message separately in another buffer. Or you can show it sequentially, before or after some other message (or prompt), using `sit-for` or `sleep-for` to pause for it to be read.

Comment: I think I'll go for another buffer. I'ìì just need to resize this new buffer's window, lets say, 1/4 of the main buffer's window.

Comment: @Drew I updated my question. Do you think I should have opened another thread?

Comment: Please consider rewriting and retitling the question, so it expresses better what you really want to ask. If it's easier to just start over with a new question and delete this one, you can of course do that instead. It's about making what you want clear, so you get the best help possible (and possibly help others too). It's up to you how best to do that. Thx.

Comment: @Drew Done, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never encountered any issue with the cursor's colour, so it may still be off for you, but the other issue seems fixed in this version,

```lisp
(defmacro with-user-explanation (MESSAGE &rest body)
  "DOCSTRING."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(let* ((temp-buffer-resize-mode temp-buffer-resize-mode)
          (frame-config (current-frame-configuration))
          (fit-frame-to-buffer t)
          (temp-buffer-show-function
           (lambda (bufname)
             (display-buffer bufname '(display-buffer-at-bottom)))))
     (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (with-output-to-temp-buffer "REPLACEMENT INFO"
             (princ ,MESSAGE))
           (fit-window-to-buffer (get-buffer-window "REPLACEMENT INFO"))
           (set-window-dedicated-p (get-buffer-window "REPLACEMENT INFO") t)
           ,@body)
       ;; *CLEANUP*
       (progn
         (kill-buffer "REPLACEMENT INFO")
         (set-frame-configuration frame-config)))))

(defun my-ue-test ()
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((a (point-min-marker))
           (z (point-max-marker)))
      (with-user-explanation
          "This message provide info about this specific string replacement in the document."
        (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil a z)))))
```

I've set the `temp-buffer-show-function` (that's where you can choose where to place the `REPLACEMENT INFO` buffer's window. I chose at the bottom, you can see the other options in the documentation of `display-buffer`) and replaced `(temp-buffer-resize-mode 1)` and `(resize-temp-buffer-window)` with `(fit-window-to-buffer (get-buffer-window "REPLACEMENT INFO"))`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your solution helps, but doesn't fix the cursor issue. Moreover I spotted another issue if BODY opens another temp-buffer's window (e.g. `occur`).

Comment: The `occur` issue is fixed by adding `(set-window-dedicated-p (get-buffer-window "REPLACEMENT INFO") t)` after `(fit-window-to-buffer (get-buffer-window "REPLACEMENT INFO"))`.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi When does the problem with the cursor occur? Is it when the function finishes because there are no more words to replace, when you quit it with `C-g`, or both?

Comment: It doesn't appear if I comment the string `(set-frame-configuration frame-config)`.

Comment: I think I could try to let-bind the cursor status variabie... But I don't now how to do it. Moreover, if I set the cursor's color with `set-cursor-color` (interactively) "before" calling the function, the cursor's color doesn't change after the function call.

Comment: Ok, I consider solved this question. I'll open another one for the cursur's color issue. Thanks.

Comment: I've fixed the occur issue in the answer. Sorry for the cursor but it never changed colour during my testing (with `emacs -Q`, v. 27.1).