# Cursor's color differs from what specified in the frame parameters

Tags: cursor

This question is related to this one: [resize-temp-buffer doesn't work in my code when 2 windows are diplayed into the frame](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63226/15606)

If I open emacs from scratch and I evaluate:

```el
(frame-parameter nil 'cursor-color)
```

I get: `"#4c4c4c"` that is a shade of gray (https://www.color-hex.com/color/4c4c4c). But my cursor is diplayed "white":

[image]

What's controlling the cursor color?

If I use `current-frame-configuration` and `set-frame-configuration` like in the related question, the cursor color is turned into grey.

I'm using GUI emacs on Ubuntu-mate 20.04, Emacs version 26.3.

I also have:

```el
(custom-set-variables '(frame-background-mode (quote dark)))
```

in my .emacs, and I suspect that this cause the issue.

Comment: Are you using Emacs in a terminal or are you using GUI Emacs? What's your platform?

Comment: GUI emacs on Ubuntu-mate 20.04, Emacs version 26.3.

Comment: Please put such info in the question - it might help. (Comments can be deleted at any time.)

Comment: Do you get the same thing if you start with `emacs -q`?

Comment: @NickD Indeed if I start with `emacs -q` the cursor is grey!

Comment: So something in your init file sets it to white.

Comment: Yes. It's `(custom-set-variables '(frame-background-mode (quote dark)))`.